# invoking a powershell command from a web api for multiple requests

Tags: powershell

I am developing an API which needs to invoke powershell commands for each request (dont ask me why).  Is there some limitation on this, I mean is powershell designed to be used in the manner from the server ?  I did a bit of research on the web and did not find anything addressing this.

Comment: Can you add a little bit more context? Where command must be executed (server, vm, ...)? Which technology is used to implement API? Should it execute the command on the same server where API is located, or remote server? Which identity is used by application and which rights it has?

Comment: Basically execute PowerShell commands is the same as execute a normal command line commands from application viewpoint